# Use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate to update array field

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, parameterized, jdbctemplate

I have a double precision array field `dblArrayFld` in a table `myTable` and I'd like to update it using Spring's `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` (I'm using Postgres).

I'm running code like this:

```
SqlParameterSource params = (new MapSqlParameterSource())
        .addValue("myarray", myDblArrayListVar)
        .addValue("myid", 123);

namedJdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE myTable SET dblArrayFld = :myarray WHERE idFld = :myid", params);
```

This returns an error that reads syntax error at or near "$2"

I'm assuming my syntax on :myarray is at fault here.  I've also tried encasing `:myarray` in the following ways:

- `dblArrayFld={:myarray}`
- `dblArrayFld={ :myarray }`
- `dblArrayFld=[:myarray]`
- `dblArrayFld=ARRAY[:myarray]`
- `dblArrayFld=(:myarray)`

What's the correct syntax here?

Comment: What type is myDblArrayListVar?

Comment: Sorry, missed that one: myDblArrayListVar is an ArrayList<Double>

Comment: I was expecting this answer but wanted to get confirmation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wehn you try to bind Collection or array as named parameter, `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` explodes the appropriate named parameter in your statement into a number of positional parameters matching the length of your array / collection. This is useful for `WHERE column IN (:param)` statements, but is not going to work in this case.

In order to set an actual Postgres array you have to supply your parameter as [`java.sql.Array`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html). You can create its instance using [Connection#createArrayOf()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createArrayOf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) method.

Comment: I think JDBC might define createArrayOf as standard but Postgres JDBC4 doesn't seem to support it.  Any good alternatives?

Comment: The latest JDBC does. Actually, it did for a while: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/changes.html#version_8.3-dev602

Comment: How do you get access to Connection in NamedParameterJdbcTemplate?

Comment: I could not find a solution so far. The best possibility I have found so far would be to use JdbcTemplate and PreparedStatementSetter but then I would have to give up on using named parameters.

Comment: @Sasa `Array array = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations().execute(new ConnectionCallback<Array>() {
   @Override
   public Array doInConnection(Connection con) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
    return con.createArrayOf("array type", arrayElements);
   }
  });`

Comment: @ChssPly76, thanks but are you sure that connection used to create array is the same one that will be used for subsequent query? I think that not, and I am not sure if that is well defined behavior. If you look in PostgreSQL JDBC driver, you can see that PgArray actually stores a reference to connection. I am afraid that using such object might lead to some strange things.

My current solution is to override getPreparedStatementCreator and return brand new implementation of statement creator that can handle such case.

Comment: @Sasa As long as you run the above code in the same transactional context as your subsequent NamedParameterJdbcTemplate queries  the session and ergo the connection will be the same.